# Use switch with selected value of static dropdown

Tags: razor, switch-statement, dropdown

I have static dropdown which populates from viewmodel. In my view, depends on selected value I want to call relevant action method.

Here is my vm:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Item 3" },
        };
        }
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var vm = new CategoryViewModel();
        return View(vm);
    }
```

and this is how I use it my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values)
```

So I tried to do this, but my message variable doesn't populate at all:

```
@switch (Model.SelectedValue)
{
case "1":
    message = "Category 1";
    // later I will replace this, with action call: @Html.Action("Realty")
    break;
case "2":
    message = "Category 2";
    // TODO
    break;
case "3":
    message = "Category 3";
    // TODO
    break;
}
```